# Merge two file skip last row of 1 file with awk

Tags: awk, files, gawk, join

I'm trying to join two files removing duplicate head row and take only 1 last row

for example:

File1.txt

```
head1
data1
data2
tail8
```

File2.txt

```
head1
data3
data4
tail9
```

results desired in file3.txt:

```
head1
data1
data2
data3
data4
tail8 or rail9 doesn't matter
```

I try first this to remove duplicate head:

`awk '!seen[$0]++' file1.txt file2.txt > file3.txt`

second command is:

`awk 'NR > 1 { print prev } { prev = $0 }' file3.txt > file4.txt`

but result is with tail in the middle of file4.txt, not to the end

```
head1
data1
data2
tail8
data3
data4
```

Any idea? Thank you in advance

Comment: Well, do you know for sure that the header is the only duplicated line? Then you do not need to check all other lines with `!seen[$0]++` and can do as Paul suggests below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{ if (NR>1) print prev; prev=$0; next } FNR>1' file1 file2
head1
data1
data2
data3
data4
tail9
```

Comment: That's works fine... except my files has many colums such "data1, abc, cde etc etc" and this example get only first $1, I change code with $0 and now works fine

Comment: another problems, code fails if one of two file are empty, now I try with sed

Comment: Yeah, I should have used $0 instead of $1, fixed now. Having said that, if your real data has multiple columns then you should provide sample data with multiple columns.

Comment: If your real data could have empty files then you should state that in your question and provide  examples where each file is empty. All we have to go on when trying to help you come up with a solution is what you tell/show us in your question.

Comment: I ask, maybe file are not complete empty but head and tail still always present, there is nothing to worry about, thank you

Answer (score 3):

Why awk? This would work:

```
{ sed -e '$d' file1.txt; sed -e '1d' file2.txt; } > file3.txt
```

Comment: yes, but I work in windows environment and I use gawk, I prefer don't install others tools, but it there's no other solution would be great use sed

Comment: or `head -n -1 file1; tail -n +2 file2`.